# ios - UIButton highlight setting act weird

Tags: ios, uibutton, highlight

My highlighted images show different.
Here is my situation.

```
[button setImage:"normal image" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:"hover image" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[button setImage:"hover image" forState:UIControlStateSelected];

- (IBAction)buttonTouched:(id)sender {
    UIButton *selectButton = sender;


    if (_currentSelectedTabButton.tag == selectButton.tag) {
        //TODO refresh view controller
        return ;
    }

    _currentSelectedTabButton.selected = NO;
    selectButton.selected = YES;

    _currentSelectedTabButton = selectButton;
}
```

1. Touch button.
2. Button shows highlighted image. (correct image)
3. Button's state is set to "selected"
4. Touch button.
5. Button shows different highlighted image.

When a button is in selected state, highlighted images show incorrectly.
Any ideas?

Comment: if you always set the button to selected (selectButton.selected = YES;) when its pressed then it doesnt change state after the first click, is that intentional?

Comment: That is part of my source. I will append whole source of method. It is always selected. If i select another button, previously selected button's selected property change to NO, currently selected button's selected property change to YES.

Comment: This is becuse when you set the setImage:forControllState:UIControlStatesSelected;

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are setting both the setImage:forControllState:UIControlStatesSelected and setHighlighted image and when you press button for first time its state being unselected the highlighted image is displayed and upon again pressing the button it shows the selected image since now the button is in selected state. (in short highlighted image will work in non-selected state of button only).

Comment: Thanks nick. I should set (UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighed) state.

Answer (score 0):

UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted  is a state is independent of UIControlStateHighLighed